# Finding, for each $\alpha < \omega_1$, an ordinal $\beta > \alpha$ such that $L_{\beta + 1} \models \beta \text{ is countable}$

Tags: set-theory

I would like to prove the following statement:

> Assume $V = L$. Then for each ordinal $\alpha < \omega_1$, there exists an ordinal $\beta > \alpha$ such that $L_{\beta + 1} \models \beta \text{ is countable}$.

For my first pass at a proof, I considered a countable elementary substructure $M$ of $L_{\omega_1}$ such that $\alpha \subseteq M$. Since $L_{\omega_1} \models \text{all ordinals are countable}$, $M \models \text{all ordinals are countable}$; further, since it can be shown via a condensation argument that $M$ is transitive, there exists a limit ordinal $\beta < \omega_1$ such that $\alpha < \beta$ and $M = L_{\beta}$. Thus, in $L_{\beta}$, all ordinals $\beta'$ are countable, and so for each $\beta'$, there exists a surjection $f_{\beta'} : \omega \rightarrow \beta'$. My hope was then to combine these $f_{\beta'}$ into a definable subset $f$ of $L_{\beta}$ such that $f : \omega \rightarrow \beta$ is surjective. Then this $f$ would belong to $L_{\beta + 1}$, and so $L_{\beta + 1}$ would think that $\beta$ is countable. However, because the union over the $f_{\beta'}$ is not necessarily a function and because I can't come up with any other way to combine the functions, I am stumped. Is there a better way to use the $f_{\beta'}$? Is there a better way to approach this question entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having $L_{\alpha+1}\models$ "$\alpha$ is countable" is a strong countability property - this means that we *don't* want $\alpha$ to be $\omega_1$-like, so we emphatically don't want to look at things like elementary submodels of $L_{\omega_1}$. In particular, a club of countable ordinals will **not** have the desired property (take e.g. set of Mostowski collapse images of $\omega_1^M$ for $M$ a countable transitive model of $L_{\omega_2}$).

Instead, note that the desired condition is the same as "$L_\alpha$ has a definable bijection between $L_\alpha$ and $\omega$" (since the stuff in $L_{\alpha+1}$ is exactly the stuff definable in $L_\alpha$, and $L_\alpha$ has a bijection between itself and $\alpha$). One nice way for a level of $L$ to see its own countability is for it to$^1$ be the first level of $L$ satisfying some sentence with hereditarily countable parameters:

> Suppose $L_\eta$ satisfies enough of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, $a\in \mathsf{HC}^{L_\eta}$, and there is a formula $\varphi$ such that $L_\eta$ is the least level of $L$ containing $a$ as an element and satisfying $\varphi(a)$. Let $f_1,...,f_n$ be definable-over-$L_\eta$ Skolem functions for $\varphi(a)$, and - in $L_\eta$ - let $C$ be the Mostowski collapse of the closure of $tc(\{a\})$ under the Godel operations and the $f_i$s We have that $C$ is definable (scince we've only used bounded-quantifier-rank "tools" to build $C$ - regardless of how complicated $\varphi$ is, there are only finitely many Skolem functions we need), $a\in C$ (since we folded in the transitive closure), and $L_\eta\models$ "$C$ is countable" (since $a\in\mathsf{HC}^{L_\eta}$), so by assumption we get $C=L_\eta$.

And we can now apply this in a very silly way:

> For each $a\in L_{\omega_1}$ consider the least level of $L$ which sees that $a$ is hereditarily countable.

---

$^1$Actually, we also need $L_\eta$ to satisfy a small fragment of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ as well. But I do mean a **small** fragment - we just need $L_\eta$ to be able to perform basic recursive constructions, a la Lowenheim-Skolem and Mostowski. So in partcular, $\mathsf{KP}$ is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Just to check my own understanding -- the set $C$ that you construct is a definable subset of $L_{\eta}$ and not an element of $L_{\eta}$, right?

Comment: @gaiuscassiuslonginus Yup. It's definable because it's the closure of a definable set (indeed an element) under finitely many definable operations, and it's not an element of $L_\eta$ since if it were it would be a smaller level of $L_\eta$ (containing $a$ as an element and) satisfying $\varphi(x)$, which can't happen by assumption on $\eta$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! One more question (sorry) -- since I'm not very familiar with Gödel functions, I'm trying to adapt your proof to avoid mentioning them: Let $a \in L_{\omega_1}$, and let $\eta$ be least such that $L_{\eta} $ sees $a$ is hereditarily countable. Let $M$ be a countable elementary submodel of $L_{\eta}$ such that $\text{tc}(\left\{a \right\}) \subseteq M$, and let $N$ be its transitive collapse. Then by minimality of $\eta$, $N = L_{\eta}$, and $N$ is countable in $L_{\eta + 1}$ by a definability argument. Is this equivalent to your proof?

Comment: @gaiuscassiuslonginus no, it's not - all that gives us is that $L_\eta$ is *externally* countable. We need $L_\eta$ to be *internally* countable. The issue with the argument in your comment is that in order to get what we want we would need $M$, or $M$'s Mostowski collapse more accurately, to be definable in $L_\eta$ - which a priori it isn't. This is what the argument in my answer does: it explicitly builds the desired object in a definable way. The spirit is the same, but we need to do more work.

Comment: I see! Thank you again; this has been very helpful.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You also need Skolem functions to ensure that $C$ satisfies your fragment of ZFC. The Gödel operations alone will only ensure that you get something of the form $L_\gamma$. But here it is crucial that your small fragment is finite or at least of bounded complexity (which KP is) so that these Skolem functions are uniformily definable over $L_\eta$. For example, the argument obviously cannot work if we take full ZFC. Am I right? (Maybe that's implicit in your answer)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another argument that migth be more more straightforward (Noah's answer is very insightful though).

Let us write $\alpha_0 = \alpha$ and define inductively $\alpha_{n+1}$ to be least so that $L_{\alpha_{n+1}} \models$ "$\alpha_n$ is countable". This means that $L_{\alpha_{n+1}}$ contains the $<_L$-least bijection $f_n$ between $\alpha_n$ and $\omega$. Now take $\beta = \sup_{n \in \omega} \alpha_n$. Then we see that in $L_{\beta}$ the sequence $\langle \alpha_n : n \in \omega \rangle$ is definable (from the parameter $\alpha$) since we could have carried out the whole inductive construction (which is absolute between levels of the $L$ hierarchy) in $L_\beta$. Also the sequence $\langle f_n : n \in \omega \rangle$ is definable over $L_\beta$. Now it is easy (say, using Cantor's diagonal argument) to use these functions to define a bijection $f$ between $\beta$ and $\omega$. $f$ is then definable over $L_\beta$.

Note that according to Noah's argument, $\alpha_1$ will already work for "most" (club many) $\alpha$. But this will always be a successor ordinal. Here we got a limit ordinal.